Explaining syntax of the to_date function in QGIS Expression
In QGIS 3.16 I have loaded a CSV file with the following format:

and joined it to a shapefile.
I am trying to build an expression within Symbology and have tried various ways, one of which:
"Metric" = 'Signal Strength' AND to_date("DT", 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'en') > to_date("15/04/2024", 'dd/mm/yyyy', 'en')

I don't get any errors, but I get 0 features returned. The example file format shows there should be at least 3 features returned. Any ideas about what is incorrect with my expression?

Check the format_date function in the Field Calculator (Date and Time) for a description of supported format tokens and how they are mapped. Hint: mm relates to Minute, MM to Month (both with leading 0).

Thanks very much for the hint. All sorted now.
